# Python : Check an inputs first characters

Tags: python, input, character

Okay so i have a problem i looked it up but didnt know exactly what to look up and kept seeing problems that had nothing to do with mine.. So my problem here is im taking an input in python

```
flashSite = raw_input('[?] Please Provide a Web Url : ')
```

After it takes the input i want it to check if the http:// characters are included in the beginning of the input , if they are then dont add them in again , if they arent then add them in for the user , Help is greatly appreciated.. Also im new to Stackoverflow so i will have problems with little things like putting code in comments and such:(

edit :
So from other answers and comments i came out with this

```
def ScrapeFlashFiles():
flashSite = raw_input('Please Provide a web URL : ')
if flashSite.lower().startswith(flashSite, beg=0, end=7('http://')):
    return flashSite
elif flashSite.lower().startswith(flashSite, beg=0, end=4('www.')):
    flashSite = 'http://' + flashSite
print ' Sending requests... '
flashReq = requests.get(flashSite)
print ' Scraping content '
flashTree = html.fromstring(flashReq.content)
print 'Searching for keyword \'.swf\' '
for line in flashReq.content.split('\n'):
    if '.swf' in line:
        print line
print 'Flash Scrape Complete..'
```

Am i doing something wrong here?

Note i am a beginner.. Im getting an error now talking about an int..

Source to where i was reading about the startswith method
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_startswith.htm

Comment: Have a look at the `startswith` method of strings

Comment: So, possibly create an if statement using the startswith method using the beg and end parameters ?

Comment: too simple it is. when you got the input, check the first 7 characters by this: if slashSite[0:7]=="http://" ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

raw_input returns a string, as visible from the documentation: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#

Since you're working with a string Type, you can use any of the string methods https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods.

For example:

```
expected_beginning = 'http://'
if not flashSite.startswith(expected_beginning):
  flashSite = expected_beginning + flashSite
```

You could do interesting things, like make sure it's always lowercase by doing:

```
if not flashSite.lower().startswith(expected_beginning):
```

etc.

Comment: I Just Coded something like that in but i didnt know about the if not i used an if and an elif.. is that bad practice?

Comment: My opinion is that your code should be in the generally "same style" all the way through. Using ifs and elifs is not bad. In this case, I decided to do the "if not" clause in order to decrease the number of lines.

Remember that "clever" code can be more confusing, so it's not harmful to add lines as long as your code is easier to read.

Comment: Ahh okay , That makes sense